# Not null timestamp column is sometimes updated to null

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a problem with a column in our database

We have a column defined as

```sql
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The problem being sometimes at random it's updated to NULL. We do not insert the timestamp, relying on the database to insert it.

The databse is MySQL 5.6 on Amazon Web Services RDS

How can this happen?

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: Only a one that watches for changes and if they happen inserts them into a `changelog` column. The triggers do not ever touch this `updated_at` column though

Comment: That doesn't seem possible 'If the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, TIMESTAMP columns by default are NOT NULL, cannot contain NULL values, and assigning NULL assigns the current timestamp' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: I speculate that the rows with nulls did not get those null values from the update in question.  Can you make your question reproducible?

Comment: Thank you guys, yeah, it happens at random, I think it might be connected to database configuration. I don't seem to find a way to make it reproducible. It's part of a big system and seems to happen completly randomly. No pattern

Comment: I'd suggest enabling and inspecting the query log.